# Using love2d and Lua. My platform spawn function doesn't work

Tags: lua, love2d

First I create the functions that will spawn and check collisions:

```
floors = {}

function makeFloor(x, y, w, h)
    floor = {}
    floor.x = x
    floor.y = y
    floor.w = w
    floor.h = h

    table.insert(floors, floor)
end

function checkCollision(x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2)
    return  x1 < x2+w2 and 
            x2 < x1+w1 and
            y1 < y2+h2 and
            y2 < y1+h1
end
```

I then I call the makeFloor() funciton for every platform I want to spawn (its primitive I know), check the collisions and draw the the platforms:

```
-- place platforms
makeFloor(750, 600, 300, 10)
makeFloor(20, 500, 700, 10)


--check collision
for i, f in ipairs(floors) do
    if checkCollision(player.x,player.y,player.w,player.h,f.x,f.y,f.w,f.h) then
        player.isGrounded = true
        player.canJump = true
    else player.isGrounded = false
        player.canJump = false
    end
end

end

function gameDraw()

    for i, f in ipairs(floors) do
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", f.x, f.y, f.w, f.h)
    end
end
```

The collision check only works on the last platform called, can someone please explain what logic I am not seeing here? Why does it ignore the first platform? Is it being over-ridden?

Answer (score 1):

You're erasing results of previous collision checks when you assign false to `.isGrounded` and `.canJump` fields in the `else` clause of collision check.

Do not assign false after every check. Instead initialize those fields to false just before entering the loop, and only assign true when collision found.